# Spyder + Anaconda: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I use Ubuntu 17.10 together with Anaconda + Spyder for python3. My problem is:

When I click on the variable viewer in Spyder and the variable is e.g. a `numpy array` I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'numpy'",)`, even though I can import numpy and work with it in my script. Furthermore, autocomplete also does not work with packages.

I checked via `sys.prefix` and it is set to `'/home/my_name/anaconda3'`.

I would really appreciate your help :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look under `conda`'s pre-install packages. do you have `numpy`? in spyder can you also try do this: `!pip install numpy`. i am bit surprised you went for `conda` in Ubuntu. Ubuntu has pretty good native support for python given they use it for building the system as well. it's probably better and less trouble if you go for virtual env + pycharm under Ubuntu. I don't know if `conda`'s using native python or not, if yes you need to be very careful that `conda` doesn't interfere with Ubuntu's local python; if by any chance `conda` screws it up, good luck re-install Ubuntu.

Comment: Conda has `numpy` preinstalled. Thanks for the tip but it is a requirement to use conda that I cannot change right now, thus I would prefer to solve the issue.

Comment: cool, no problem at all. did you try in Spyder the command I mentioned above?

Comment: As spyder already accepts numpy when I compute stuff, I don't think this fits. The problem is something in the form that spyder does not recognize conda for everything besides calculations.

Comment: @stucash the whole point of `conda` is that it doesn't tamper with the system Python in any way, but installs everything only within its own environment(s). @JimmysCheeseSteak how are you starting Spyder?

Comment: @nekomatic good to know that, I don’t use Conda so I don’t know that actually is the case, provided there is already virtual env and plenty good tools for us to separate our python from the system one, so I probably didn’t guess from that perspective and it seems conda is heavy but it does abstract away all the setup.

Comment: @nekomatic I start spyder via the ubuntu applications interface. Should I start it in some way via conda?

Comment: Sounds like "Have you tried turning it off and on again". See [Anaconda: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gower'". Module not available in conda, but only in pip. Same error even after installing with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77553301/11154841).