# Anaconda: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gower'". Module not available in conda, but only in pip. Same error even after installing with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

Consider:

```
pip install gower

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels
Collecting gower
  Using cached gower-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-2022.05-py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from gower) (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-2022.05-py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from gower) (1.21.5)
Installing collected packages: gower
Successfully installed gower-0.1.2
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Thus, it is installed, but it can only be installed with pip, not with conda, and the module cannot be found:

```py
import gower
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 import gower

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gower'
```

I also tried installing it with conda then, but it is not in the conda package manager:

```
conda install gower

Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
 - pytorch
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gower

Current channels:

  - defaults
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I am in the same virtual environment all the time during the tests, one that is offered online on Anaconda.com with "anaconda-2022.05-py39". The error is the same when switching to "anaconda-panel-2023.05-py310".

What can I do to get `import gower` to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the output of the pip installer says:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I oversaw the note and should also know about it without the note.

When I switched back to the "anaconda-2022.05-py39" virtual environment/kernel, this triggered the needed restart of the kernel, and the `gower` module was found.